# How to print head and tail of pandas without columns on tail

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I reversed my data in pandas, and I want to print both the head and tail on top of each other without the columns on the tail part.

Code:

```
import datetime 
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import csv

start = datetime.datetime(1996, 12, 16)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4)

df = pd.read_csv('Filename.txt')
df.columns = ['C1','c2','c3','c4']
df = df.set_index('C1')
reversed_df = df.iloc[::-1]

print(reversed_df.head(),reversed_df.tail())
```

Output:

```
             c2  c3  c4
C1                  
1900-12-16   8   0   0
1900-12-17   8   0   1
1900-12-18   8   0   2
1900-12-19   8   0   3
1900-12-20   8   0   4            c2  c3  c4
C1                
2000-03-30   8   0   5
2000-03-31   8   0   6
2000-04-01   8   0   7
2000-04-02   8   0   8
2000-04-03   8   0   9
```

I would like to get rid of the second (C1,c2,c3,c4) above the tail. So the output is like this below.

```
             c2  c3  c4
C1                  
1900-12-16   8   0   0
1900-12-17   8   0   1
1900-12-18   8   0   2
1900-12-19   8   0   3
1900-12-20   8   0   4           

2000-03-30   8   0   5
2000-03-31   8   0   6
2000-04-01   8   0   7
2000-04-02   8   0   8
2000-04-03   8   0   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close to what cold provided , but here I am using `drop`

```
n=5
print(df.drop(df.index[n:-n]))


df.drop(df.index[n:-n]).to_string(header=False)
```

Comment: This works but I want the data to be reversed. With the oldest data being at the top, and the newest being at the bottom.

Comment: My mistake, I needed to add the reversed_df, to reverse the data. Thank you.

Comment: @JordanGraham then just before you do my solution df = df.iloc[::-1]

Answer (score 4):

I can't make head or tail of this request, but I can make both using `pd.concat`:

```
n = 5
head_tail = pd.concat([df[:n], df[-n:]])
```

You can also print the head and tail separately. However, to remove the headers from `tail`, call `to_string` and pass `header=False`,

```
print(df.tail().to_string(header=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *add option in case 'c1' is set as row index*

I just realize your data having `c1` as row index. In that case, you just need adding `index_names=False` to `to_string`

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
            c2  c3  c4
c1
1900-12-16   8   0   0
1900-12-17   8   0   1
1900-12-18   8   0   2
1900-12-19   8   0   3
1900-12-20   8   0   4
2000-03-30   8   0   5
2000-03-31   8   0   6
2000-04-01   8   0   7
2000-04-02   8   0   8
2000-04-03   8   0   9


In [87]: print(df.head(2).to_string(header=df.columns.tolist(), index_names=False), df.tail(2).to_string(header=False, index_names=False) ,sep='\n\n')
           c2 c3 c4
1900-12-16  8  0  0
1900-12-17  8  0  1

2000-04-02  8  0  8
2000-04-03  8  0  9
```

*Note*: I use `df` for simple demonstration. Just replace `df` with `reversed_df` to get your desired output.

**Original:**
This is doable if you utilize `to_string`, `tolist`, and `print` parameters.

```
In [59]: df
Out[59]:
            c2  c3  c4
1900-12-16   8   0   0
1900-12-17   8   0   1
1900-12-18   8   0   2
1900-12-19   8   0   3
1900-12-20   8   0   4
2000-03-30   8   0   5
2000-03-31   8   0   6
2000-04-01   8   0   7
2000-04-02   8   0   8
2000-04-03   8   0   9
```

I just print out `head(2)` and `tail(2)` for demo

```
In [65]: print(df.head(2).to_string(header=df.columns.tolist()), df.tail(2).to_string(header=False) ,sep='\n\n')
           c2 c3 c4
1900-12-16  8  0  0
1900-12-17  8  0  1

2000-04-02  8  0  8
2000-04-03  8  0  9
```